# How to use WindowInsetsControllerCompat.OnControllableInsetsChangedListener?

Tags: android

I want to toggle menu UI when system ui visibility is changed.

And I think OnControllableInsetsChangedListener can be used, but I don't know how to use.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsetsController.OnControllableInsetsChangedListener

Please show me the example of OnControllableInsetsChangedListener.